# Datastore admin - Unable to resolve the server's DNS address

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to access Datastore Admin on Google App Engine but I get Unable to resolve the server's DNS address error. 
The url that cannot be translated is: [https protocol]ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-[myapp].gene.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~gene.com:[myapp]&adminconsolecustompage

I tried with adding exceptions to coookies because when I try directly access it with [http protocol][myapp].gene.com/_ah/datastore_admin I get error with redirect loop.

Any idea? Any workarounds are also welcomed - I just need to copy datastore to local environment.

Witek

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but are you using federated login? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4111

Comment: Thanks for a hint. Authentication is set to Google Apps domain and there is Authentication Domain. Is this way called "federated login"? If so is there any workaround? I cannot switch to any other type of authentication.

Comment: If I copy the link (as adviced) https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-[myapp].gene.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~gene.com:[myapp]&adminconsolecustompage to another browser or window I get the info that the page is not reachable....

Comment: If I use Incognito window I get the same error about DNS. I found that it can be the case if app name is too long but [myapp] consists of 7 signs...

Comment: Are you sure your custom domain is setup to properly route requests to your application (and more importantly in  this case -- to specific versions of your app)? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: I think so. The application is working and its different version are also accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Patrick.
Your guess turned out to be the right one. The domain is not set up properly and this is the reason of problems.