# Google App Engine (Java) custom page is "Unable to resolve the server's DNS address" caused by corrupted Application Settings. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dns

I'm trying to display a custom admin page in the "Custom" section of GAE's admin console (Java). I've got the html file in the war directory. My appengine-web.xml contains the admin-console tag:

```
<admin-console>
    <page name="Hello World" url="/helloWorld.html" />
</admin-console>
```

To view the custom admin page, I need to deploy to app engine (searching on stack overflow I found that custom pages do not show up in the dev environment). When I deploy, **I see the link under the "Custom" section** as "Hello World". When I click on it, I get an error message:

```
Unable to resolve the server's DNS address
```

You can find a screenshot of the error message here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/656P9.jpg

Debugging steps taken:

1. Is the html page available when I try to access it directly. i.e. *app-id.appspot.com/helloWorld.html*?
   Yes
2. If I create a new app in app engine (let's call this app2) and deploy this **same code**, can I access the custom page from within the admin console?
   Yes
3. If I create a new app **by copying the settings from my original app** (let's call this app3) using the "Duplicate Application Settings" from Application Settings in the Admin Console and then deploy this **same code**, can I access the custom page from within the admin console?
   **No**
4. Are the Application Settings of app2 and app3 the same (Application Settings is accessible from the Admin Console)?
   **Yes** (except for the "Application Title" and "Application Identifier")
5. Am I using a Custom domain? [1]
   No
6. Am I using Google Accounts API for the "Authentication Type"? [1]
   Yes

[1] Stack Overflow post: [Datastore admin - Unable to resolve the server's DNS address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251536/datastore-admin-unable-to-resolve-the-servers-dns-address)

**This leads me to believe that my Application Settings are somehow corrupted and I cannot fix this from the Application Settings section in the Admin Console. Is there a way that I can "clean" my Application Settings or "restore to factory defaults" to fix this, without affecting the data in my app?**

Any help with how to fix this is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I posted this on HN for more exposure, link to discussion: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9443973

Comment: try deploying a new version name and deleting the old default version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments suggested that I redeploy with a new version name and delete the old version. that did the trick! thanks @jirungaray